# Atributo shrink-to-fit-no en <meta name="viewport">

Tags: html5

La pregunta consta básicamente de lo que ven en el titulo, y he visto dicho atributo en muchas plantillas y trabajos últimamente...

¿Alguien me puede decir para qué funciona? Aparte de eso ¿cuál es la mejor manera de escribir esta meta etiqueta con sus atributos? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Te recomendaría que separases la pregunta en dos: por una parte `shrink-to-fit`, y por otra la meta etiqueta del viewport. Aunque esta segunda pregunta puede ser demasiado genérica y casi te recomendaría que leyeses la [página de MDN sobre viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/M%C3%B3vil/Viewport_meta_tag) y luego hacer una pregunta más concreta.

Answer (score 1):

> Esto es una traducción (adaptada) de la [respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33949647/3695983) para una [pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767533/what-does-the-shrink-to-fit-viewport-meta-attribute-do) que hay en el sitio en inglés. Si esta respuesta te sirve, acéptala y visita la respuesta original para darle un voto positivo.

---

`"shrink-to-fit=no"` es algo específico de Safari, al menos al momento de escribir esta respuesta, y se introdujo como parte de Safari 9.0. Citando la sección "¿Qué hay nuevo en Safari?" de la [documentación para Safari 9.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH9-SW36):

> ## Cambios en el Viewport
>
> Los meta tags Viewport que usan `"width=device-width"` causarán que la página se escale (hacia abajo) para ajustarse a los contenidos que sobresalen de los límites del viewport. Puedes anular este comportamiento añadiendo `"shrink-to-fit=no"` a tu meta tag como se muestra más abajo. El valor añadido prevendrá que la página se escale para ajustarse al viewport.
>
> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">`

Resumiendo, añadir eso al meta tag (o meta-etiqueta) del viewport hará que se restablezca el comportamiento de las versiones anteriores a Safari 9.0.

---

## Ejemplo

Aquí dejo un ejemplo visual que muestra la diferencia después de cargar la página con ambas configuraciones.

La sección en rojo es el ancho del viewport y la sección azul está posicionada fuera del viewport inicial (e.g. `left: 100vw`). Puedes ver como en el primer ejemplo la página tiene zoom para ajustarse cuando `shrink-to-fit=no` se omite (por tanto mostrando el contenido que hay fuera del viewport), y la zona azul se mantiene fuera de la pantalla en el segundo ejemplo.

El código de este ejemplo se puede encontrar en este [Codepen](https://codepen.io/davidjb/pen/ENGqpv).

#### Sin especificar `shrink-to-fit`

[image: Sin shrink-to-fit=no]

#### Con `shrink-to-fit=no`

[image: Con shrink-to-fit=no]